# Powershell open Excel Pivot Table and Edit it

Tags: excel, powershell, pivot-table

I'm trying to open an excel file via Powershell and there is one field I am interested in changing through the powershell script, but I can't get it to work. The field I want to change is a drop down menu wtih a list of names. I want to be able to open the Pivot Table and set the dropdown menu to a certain name.

This is what I have so far for my Pivot Table named PivotTable1 and the field name is called ALERT_STATUS. It is just opening up the Pivot Table in excel and selecting the field name. How can I tell it to change the dropdown on the ALERT_STATUS field to be something specific?

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.Visible = $True
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\myuser\Documents\ExampleFile.xlsx")

$pivotsheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1) 
$pivotfields = $pivotsheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ALERT_STATUS")
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out, but have literally never used powershell. But here's some tips that might help. When you select an item in a pivot table drop down, what you are really doing is making all other items not visible. So if you can get the PivotItems for that PivotField... and then iterate through them... if you make everything that is not correct `.visible = false` then it will have the same result.